# find equation of tangent and normal lines (differentiation)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

What is the equation of the tangent and normal lines to this function at the point p

$f(x)$ = $x^3$ at the point $p = (2,8)$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent#Equations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we take the derivative of $f(x)$

$f'(x) = 3x^2, \tag{1}$

the evaluate it at $x = 2$ to obtain the slope at $(2, 8)$:

$f'(2) = 3(2)^2 = 12. \tag{2}$

Knowing this, we have that the tangent line, that is, the line of slope $12$ passing through the point $(2, 8)$, is given by

$y - 8 = 12(x - 2), \tag{3}$

or

$y = 12x - 16. \tag{4}$

The normal line obeys a similar equation but its slope is $-\frac{1}{12}$; thus

$y - 8 = -\frac{1}{12}(x - 2), \tag{5}$

or

$y = -\frac{1}{12}x + \frac{49}{6} \tag{6}$

are equations for the normal line.  QED.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as alwaus,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: if i had $ g(x) = \frac 1x $ at the point $p=(1,1)$ . its tangent line equation gonna be $ y= 1 + \frac 1x^2 (x-1)$ and its normal line equation gonna be $ y= 1-x^2(x-1)$ , right ?

Comment: No, Tennisman. $g'(x) = -\frac 1{x^2}$, and so $g'(1) = -\frac 1{1^2} = -1$. That would be the slope of the tangent line, whose equation will be $$y = 1 + -1(x - 1) = 1 - (x - 1) = 2 - x$$ The slope of the normal line will be $- - \frac 11 = 1$, giving you the equation $$y - 1 = 1(x - 1) \iff y = 1 + (x - 1) = x$$

Comment: To Tennisman:  you're most welcome, glad to be of service!

Answer (score 2):

To find the slope of the needed lines, first find $f'(x)$ and evaluate at $x = 2$, since $p = (2, 8)$ is a point on both lines. The slope $m_1$ of the *tangent line* will equal $m_1 = f'(2)$. The slope $m_2$ of the *normal line* will equal $m_2 = -\dfrac 1{f'(2)} = -\dfrac 1{m_1}$.

For both lines you then have the slope, and the point on those lines: $(2, 8)$.

The point-slope form of an equation of a line with a given slope $m$ and which intersects the point $(x_0, y_0)$, is given by $$y - y_0 = m(x - x_0)$$

Comment: $\ddot\smile$ and +)

Answer (score 0):

A line is determined by a slope and a point  You have a point, $(2,8)$. Now obtain the slopes.